# Factless Fact Table has 1:1 Relationship with Dimension Table

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensions, dimensional-modeling, fact-table

[image: Data Source View]

I'm reviewing old data warehouse & I have encountered unusual 1: 1 relationship between factless fact table (Fact_contact) &  Dim_Incident.

In general, Fact_Contact is used for recording cases/tickets/enquiries. Some of the customers are anonymous; therefore, there are uniqueCustRef & CustomerRef "facts" that are used for distinct count.

1:1 relationship between fact & dimension tables does not feel right. Is it a recommended solution? Currently, there is no documentation why it was designed the way it was.

Thank you.

Comment: [There a proposal for a dedicated Q&A site for Business Intelligence. Follow, Post and Support to get it up.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be right; this does not look right.
The FactContact

should not have the incidentId

I do not know the requirements but logically thinking I would suggest the following;

```
IncidentType - what is the type of incident that is logged
FirstIncidentId - the first incident corresponding to the customer/IncidentType
FirstIncidentDate - Date of the above incident
LastIncidentId - the last incident corresponding to the customer/incidenttype - when there is only one incident you will have the firstincidentid and lastincidentid the same
LastIncidentDate - the date of the above incident
IncidentCount - the number of incidents for the customer/incidenttype combination
```

Hope this helps